# Filtering and Search in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, filter

i am new in code igniter,  how to filtering and search in code igniter?
This is database

[image]

i have no idea how filter data i will fetch datas to list i have two tbls doctor and spacialisation –
the search box like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0zJi.png)

Comment: help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please describe what you have tried until now.

Comment: i have another table   (tbl specialisation)                                                                         ======>>                     spec_id | dept_id | spec_spacilisaton  ====>>  these are fields

Comment: if we select speacialisation and click ent if show all ent's in view and next select box show ent's distrtct if we click a district the ent's are in that district only show

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/ - thats the help you need - if you've phpmyadmin successfully connected to a db, you'll manage it with CI too...

Comment: u know in flipcart the side filtering option  companey ,price , color like same as that